# Organizing committee of conference announced publication of papers, but one year later, this hasn't happened. What to do?

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, publishers, political-science

I participated one year ago in a conference. The organizing committee asserted that they were planning to produce a publication from the papers presented at the conference and they announced they secured a contract with Palgrave, but I haven’t received any updates regarding the book since the conference. By the way, The Association which organized the conference has a good reputation. Should I send an email to ask them about the book? What’s the best formula for such email ?Thank you

Comment: Do you think they may have been affected by Covid19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email to the conference or program chair would certainly be appropriate. You don't need any format for it. Just say you are wondering if the book is still in progress and when it might be expected.

As Solar Mike implies in a comment, the coronavirus might have disrupted this, like many other things. But it can also take a while to produce a physical book, especially for conference proceedings when not done by the association itself. The publisher has higher priorities, most likely.

I know of one conference where the papers from one annual meeting are only available at the next. The publisher is a university press.